# How to fix a SQL statement that is not working properly?

Tags: sql, vb.net, winforms

**Updated**

The winform has a datetimepicker 4 regular texboxes and 2 masked texboxes and a bound datagridview.

I'm using the cellformatting event of the datagridview to lookup the employees' names from another datatable. To accomplish this I'm using a sql statement that for the most part is working.

As it is right now it returns the employees names from different columns on the second datatable and sets them in the second column of the datagridview right after employee ID as intended.

The part that is NOT working is looking at the termination date ("FSalida" column) and returning  the employees name only if it doesn't have a termination date or the selected date is earlier than the termination date. In other words if the employee has been terminated it shouldn't appear after the termination date.

The code that I have is this:

```
 Private Sub PartePersonalDataGridView_CellFormatting(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellFormatting
    'This looks up the employee's full name using the employee number from the ID column (first column) 
    Try
        Dim dgvr As DataGridViewRow = DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex)
        If dgvr.Cells(0).Value IsNot Nothing AndAlso dgvr.Cells(0).Value IsNot DBNull.Value Then
            Dim empID As Integer = CInt(dgvr.Cells(0).Value)
            Dim qry = From dr As PersonalObraDataSet.PersonalObRow In PersonalObraDataSet.PersonalOb
            Where (dr.cdTrabajador = empID) And (dr.FSalida = Nothing) Or (dr.FSalida <= txtDate.Text)
            'This returns each part of the name and joins it in the the 2nd column (name column)
            DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(1).Value = (qry.First.Nombre1 & " " & qry.First.Nombre2 & " " & qry.First.Apellido1 & " " & qry.First.Apellido2)
            DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = DefaultBackColor
        End If
        'If there is an exemption like the employee doesn't exists this turns the background color red and instead
        'of the name on the second column it shows "employee doesn't exist."
    Catch ex As Exception
        DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red
        DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(1).Value = "ESTE EMPLEADO NO EXISTE"
        Exit Sub
```

The part that is not working is after the "And":

```
Where (dr.cdTrabajador = empID) And (dr.FSalida = Nothing) Or (dr.FSalida <= txtDate.Text)
```

This is a sample of the data on the look up table

```
ProjectID   EmployeeID  DepartmentID    HIreDate    TerminationDate     Name    Middle  Last
3116        83               1      09/03/2012      27/04/2012          John        Doe     Doe2
3116        373              1      16/11/2012                          Pedro    John       Ortiz
3116        1                1      01/01/2013                          Jose      Maria   Applessed
```

Your help fixing this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You've got the solution a couple of lines above, use `DBNull.Value` instead of `Nothing`.

```
Where (dr.cdTrabajador = empID) And (dr.FSalida = DBNull.Value) Or (dr.FSalida <= txtDate.Text)
```

Alternatively, you could set the `FSalida` field to something like `DateTime.MinValue` (I believe this is the default value for DateTime anyway) in the constructor for `PersonalObRow` and check against that, for example:

```
Class PersonalObRow

Public FSalida As DateTime 'the VB Date keyword is synonymous to System.DateTime

    Public Sub New()

        FSalida = DateTime.MinValue

    End Sub

End Class
```

Or you could make it `Nullable(Of DateTime)`, which would allow you to check if it was `Nothing`, for example:

```
Class PersonalObRow

    Public FSalida As Nullable(Of DateTime) 'or Nullable(Of Date)

End Class
```

Comment: I get the error DBNull cannot be converted to 'Date' that is why I changed it to Nothing in the first place. Any other ideas?

Comment: Sorry, but i have no idea how to do either one of those. When u say se the field to DateTime.MinValue you mean like Dim Fsalida as DateTime.MinValue? as you can tell i'm very new to coding.

Comment: Nope no luck. I just don't understand why it looks up the names using the ID without any problems and really fast, but as soon as the "and" enters the code it stops working right.

Comment: Have you tried putting parentheses round your logic so it's definitely doing what you want it to? I'm not 100% on operator precedence, but doing `And ((dr.FSalida = Nothing) Or (dr.FSalida <= txtDate.Text))` will make sure it behaves as expected.

Comment: Yeah i tried it but it just doesn't work. When adding the "And" it marks all the employees as terminated or non existent.

Comment: Is `PersonalObraDataSet.PersonalOb` a variable? I don't suppose it would be possible for you to dump some sample data out so we can better understand the structure of things? =]

Comment: PersonalObraDataset is the Dataset it contains all the datatable from the MS Access database. PersonalOb is a datatable from the Dataset it contains the employee's information as project ID,employee ID, First, Middle, and last name, department, hire date, termination date. I'm not sure what you mean by dump sample data.

Comment: Well if you could put some code together that would loop over all of your data and output the values of each column, so we can see examples of what the tables contain, that would help greatly I think =]

Comment: I have no idea how to do that. I'd need to do research or start another thread to get that done. But i can see the database and i have 3 Number columns (Employee, Department and Project ID) 2 Date columns (Hire and Termination Dates) and string for the First Midle and Last name. All of this is from the PersonalOb table.

Comment: Oh ok well if you could just copy those into a rudimentary table type thing in notepad and paste the data into your question? Just so we can see an example of your data, if that's ok

Comment: The Question is Updated